# In Eclipse, What does the id after "Class" mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

As shown below:

```
c1  Class<T> (com.horstmann.corejava.Employee) (id=22)
```

I am curious about what does this id exactly mean? Can I actually modify it? And I want to know something related.

Comment: where exactly do you see that

Comment: @Xoce in the debug variables section

Answer (score 0):

That is an opaque internal (to the JVM) identifier that is unique for each object. You can think of as a "handle" for the instance.

You cannot change it, and it can be different for a given object instance every time you run your code.

It can be useful when you are stepping through your code in the debugger and have many instances of a class. You can look at two instances and determine if they are actually the same instance accessed through different references.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. Say, you have multiple instances of this class. In cases of debugging, this `id` can be a unique identifier.

The `id` is arbitrarily assigned by the eclipse debugger. My best guess would be that eclipse has some sort of an a map, something like `IdentityHashMap<Object, Integer>`, assigning a unique integer to every object.